# Is it possible to set timer with local time in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, timer, embedded-linux

I'm on my IOT project with raspberry pi,

And I want to raise event in certain time like 06:00:00 and 12:00:00

But I can't do this with jiffies because jiffies only counts the time since the os started.

I have an Idea :

I may raise interrupt every second and check local time, compare it with certain time.

But I think it is very bad way

Do you have any good idea for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a cron at 06:00:00 and 12:00:00. Trigger your event through cron.[How to create a cronjob](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

Answer (score 1):

[Crontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) and [cron](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cron) is the way to do such timing as ninja already answered.

If you need very light weight solution, and want to play with RTC. Then there is alternative solution:

RTC chips usually contain an alarm functionality. If interrupt signal is wired from RTC to CPU, then you may use it via [rtc API](http://linux.die.net/man/4/rtc) of linux.

For setting and waiting a timer you need something like this (not a complete example):

```
struct rtc_time rtc_tm = {....};

fd = open("/dev/rtc0", O_RDONLY, 0);  // Open the RTC device
ioctl(fd, RTC_AIE_ON, 0);             // Enable alarm interrupt
ioctl(fd, RTC_ALM_SET, &rtc_tm);      // Set the alarm time
read(fd, &x, sizeof(x));              // Wait the alarm
```

Complete example [here](https://risacher.org/yopy/rtc-test.c).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using cron, you can do what cron does yourself. Something like this:

```
struct timespec target = { ... };
int ret;

while((ret = clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, TIMER_ABSTIME, &target, NULL)) == EINTR)
    ;

/* if !ret, current time is $target here */
```

The loop is needed to handle possible interruption; check clock_nanosleep(2).